# Express.js req.body.variableName returning undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs, body-parser

I'm working on a website using Node.js with Express and EJS as the templating engine, and I'm having trouble getting data from the form on the site. Here is my code:

app.js

```
//app.js
'use strict';
var debug = require('debug');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var app = express();
const { getSearchPage, search } = require('./routes/search');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
       
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
  debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
        });
 
app.get('/search', getSearchPage);
app.post('/search', search);        
        
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); 
      
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

search.js

```
//search.js (in routes folder)
module.exports = {
  getSearchPage: (req, res) => {
    res.render('search.ejs');
  },
  search: (req, res) => {
    var artist = req.body.searchArtist;
    var song = req.body.searchSong;
    var genre = req.body.searchGenre;
    var decade = req.body.searchDecade;
    console.log("The variables from the page: ", req.body, artist, song, genre, decade); //logs "{} undefined undefined undefined undefined"
    if (song) {
      //query the database and return some results
    }
    res.render('search.ejs', { outputArray: outputArray });
  }
}
```

search.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" and dir="Itr">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Home</title>
    <!--link rel="stylesheet" href="css/search.css"-->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/9b28d88510.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
  <div class="search-box">
      <input class="search-txt" type="text" name="searchSong" placeholder="Type to search">
      <a class="search-btn" href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
      </a>
  </div>  

  <div class="search-box2">
    <input class="search-txt2" type="text" name="searchArtist" placeholder="Type to search">
    <a class="search-btn2" href="#">
      <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
    </a>
</div>  

<div class="search-box3">
    <input class="search-txt3" type="text" name="searchGenre" placeholder="Type to search">
    <a class="search-btn3" href="#">
      <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
    </a>
</div>  

<div class="search-box4">
    <input class="search-txt4" type="text" name="searchDecade" placeholder="Type to search">
    <a class="search-btn4" href="#">
      <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
    </a>
</div> 
<button type="submit">Search!</button>
</form>

<% if(typeof outputArray != 'undefined'){%>
 <ul>
    <% outputArray.forEach(function(song) { %>
        <li><%= song %></li>
    <% }); %>
<% } %>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried setting urlencoded({extended: }) to true and to false, I've tried changing the form type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded, I've tried changing the post to a get, I've made sure I have body-parser installed, I've tried putting the routes before the server declaration. I've read through most of the pages here on the same issue, but none of those fixes have worked for me. Even more confusingly, I'm following almost exactly with [this tutorial](https://dev.to/achowba/build-a-simple-app-using-node-js-and-mysql-19me), and I don't think I've missed anything that they did. This is my first time ever using Node.js/Express.js/EJS, but I've read through countless forum posts on this exact topic and I still can't figure out where it's going wrong.

Comment: Can you show a request body from a browser dev tools?

Comment: Usually the order is the following: modules, settings, middlewares, routes, listener. It might solve the problem.

Comment: @Anatoly I'm not exactly sure what you mean. When I console.log req.body I just get {}.

Comment: @MRB I meant the order of the lines. So first you import the modules such as ```require('express')``` then the ```app.set()``` then ```app.use()``` then ```app.get()``` (routes) and finally ```app.listen()```

Comment: @kmp That's how I had it originally, but I just tried putting everything back that way and still no luck

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Answer (score 0):

You have body parsers capable of handling requests formatted as JSON or URL Encoded data.

> ```
> app.use(bodyParser.json());
> app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
> ```

… but your form isn't using either of those:

> ```
> <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
> ```

---

You don't have any file inputs, so there is no reason to use `multipart/form-data` (which is more bandwidth intensive that the default URL encoded data).

**Remove the `enctype` attribute.**

---

If you wanted to support file inputs then you would need to support `multipart/form-data`.

One way to do that is to use the `express-fileupload` module, which the tutorial you linked to recommends but you didn't use.

Comment: Every time I remove the enctype attribute, my site stops running when I hit search/refresh the page (I don't really understand why this happens). But, I just tried this and before it stopped running it still didn't log anything to the console.

Comment: @kmp no, no error, but it still doesn't work